# Is there any way to make a bot respond with multiple messages?

Tags: discord.py

I'm pretty deep in progress with writing a discord bot, but I've hit a bump in the road. In trying to write a simple help command that would explain the use of every command so far, I realized all the information had no way of fitting in just one message — at least, not in the way I've been formatting it.

Can bots go over the base discord character limit? Is it possible for me to have a bot respond with one message, then another right after, so I don't have to worry so much about character limit? That would probably be ideal. Or, am I simply stuck making my help message as short and boring as possible to appease the nitroless character limit? Here's the basic template I've been using for my call-and-response commands so far, because like I said, the help message itself is very long, but follows this exact structure.

```
@bot.command()

async def command(ctx):

    await ctx.channel.send("response")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely send multiple messages one by one in a command. And if you don't know how long your content (to be sent) is, you could possibly use a for loop to send it.
The message character limit is 2000. If you would like to send it through embed,  title is 256 characters, description is 2048 characters, each field is 1024 characters, and total characters limit is 6000. And there is no way to make bot go beyond the character limit.

```py
@bot.command()
async def help_command(ctx):
  content = "..."  # content of your help msg
  for i in range(0, len(content), 2000):
    await ctx.send(content[i, i + 2000])  # send 2000 character limit for each msg
```

Comment: This is really helpful, and I might be able to make it work! Though, it may take some fiddling, because cutting it off at exactly 2k characters might mess with the formatting or cut in-between words.... And every time I update the command list, I'd have to re-count exactly how many characters the message is. Is there any way to break it up in a different / more specific way? Like "send message x, then send message y"? That way, I can basically format them in discord itself to make sure they don't go over 2k, and update it more easily.

Comment: @roboraven you could possibly develop a more precise algorithm to cut off the last word rather than cutting off at exactly at the 2000th character. One of the quickest way might be using `str.rindex()` to find the index of the last whitespace in these 2000 characters, and try to cut it off there.